# Angular-cli custom fonts not packaged in build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My company provides some custom company specific fonts for our web apps, how can I include this so that it gets distributed with a build? Currently I store these "*.otf" files in:

> src\assets\fonts

However, when I build for prod ("ng build -prod"), I get a 404 error on these. Of course I am including a reference to these fonts in my styles.css and they are working fine in a dev environment.

Comment: when you `ng build -prod` do the fonts get copied to the /dist folder?

Comment: Yes, the fonts folder and the fonts are there. It just seems like the bundling doesn't get created such that it recognizes this.

Comment: what version of the cli are you using? the css processing and font processing should be the same. Can you build for `dev` and `prod` and compare the generated `CSS` and see if the URLs point to the same location.